# Sound problems in ubuntu 13.04 (64bit)

Tags: 13.04, sound

yesterday i installed Ubuntu 13.04 (64bit) on my computer (i used to have windows)
when i logged in into my "account" (when the computer powered on) i noticed that i don't have sound .
i made some searches in Google to check the problem , i tried everything i saw but nothing happened .
i have : mio on ear headphones

what can i do ?
(first time on Ubuntu so if you can make the explanation easier for me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday.

Use this command.
Open terminal using ctrl+alt+T and run this command :-

```
amixer -c 0 -- sset Master -24dB
```

You should be able to hear then.

Comment: it didnt help me

Comment: Run this
pulseaudio --check
and update your question.

Comment: still not working ...